# Create JSON object with Stream Analytics query

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I'm trying to format an incoming JSON object as JSON object into output

input:

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "firstArray":[
    {
      "tid" : 9,
       "secondArray":[
         {
            "keep1" : "value1",
            "keep2" : "value2",
            "remove1" : "somevalue1",
            "remove2" : "somevalue2"
         },
         {...}
       ]
     },
     {
      "tid" : 8,
       "secondArray":[
         {
            "keep1" : "value1",
            "keep2" : "value2",
            "remove1" : "somevalue1",
            "remove2" : "somevalue2"
         },
         {...}
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter this object(remove some useless properties) and have something like this.

output:

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "firstArray":[
    {
      "tid" : 9,
       "secondArray":[
         {
            "keep1" : "value1",
            "keep2" : "value2"
         },
         {...}
       ]
     },
     {
      "tid" : 8,
       "secondArray":[
         {
            "keep1" : "value1",
            "keep2" : "value2"
         },
         {...}
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me with the query or point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with custom JavaScript function. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions